# Regarding npm package installation

Tags: npm

*I am getting below error while installing npm install -g create-react-native-app*

**the request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-native-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
registry.npmjs.org:80**

Comment: This error suggests that there's a problem looking up the domainname. Maybe a network issue?

Comment: what is your operating system? are you trying to do this in container (like docker)? are there any network issues?

Comment: OS is windows 10,network is good

Comment: Domain name? @Evert

Comment: how to resolve the issue can any one have any idea

Comment: @RaviG i think the error means that something is *not* right with your network. Either on your host machine or in a docker instance.